# How does App-Engine disambiguate custom domains with wildcards?

Tags: google-app-engine, wildcard-subdomain, disambiguation, custom-domain

If I add a custom domain like `*.example.com` to my app-engine project, I can then selectively add CNAMEs to that domain pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com to forward subdomains to this project, which will then identify versions in the project.

For example, if my project has a version called `www` and a version called `contact`, and I set the CNAMEs for `www.example.com` and `contact.example.com` to ghs.googlehosted.com, then `www.example.com` will be hosted by the `www`-version of my project and `contact.example.com` will be hosted by the `contact`-version of my project.

*For completeness: If I don't use the `*`, but instead add `www.example.com` and `contact.example.com` as custom domains to my project, both will be served according to the traffic allocation to the different project versions, whatever they may be.*

Now, things get interesting (and that's where my question comes in), if I add `*.example.com` as a custom domain to **one** project and `dataserver.example.com` to a **different** project. Now, Google App-Engine has to disambiguate whether `dataserver.example.com` refers to the `dataserver` version of the first project or to some version on the second project according to that project's traffic allocation.

When I set this up a few months back, it did (what I think is) the most logical thing: It picks the latter, since `dataserver.example.com` is more specific than `*.example.com` and should thus take precedence. But when I tried to set up another set of projects yesterday, it instead tried to serve me the `dataserver` version of the first project (which initially didn't exist, and thus I got 404s, but when I deployed a dummy one, I got that back).

Now the question is: What does App-Engine actually do? Is it random? Is it first-created, first-served? Is it by specificity, but might take a while to propagate to all servers?